# A strange section 'featured' in MVC Application example

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I use MVC 4 template example and discover a strange section 'featured'. These codes are from _Index.cshtml:

```
@section featured {
    <section class="featured">
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <hgroup class="title">
                <h1>@ViewBag.Title.</h1>
                <h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
            </hgroup>
            <p>
                To learn more about ASP.NET MVC visit
                <a href="http://asp.net/mvc" title="ASP.NET MVC Website">http://asp.net/mvc</a>.
                The page features <mark>videos, tutorials, and samples</mark> to help you get the most from ASP.NET MVC.
                If you have any questions about ASP.NET MVC visit
                <a href="http://forums.asp.net/1146.aspx/1?MVC" title="ASP.NET MVC Forum">our forums</a>.
            </p>
        </div>
    </section>
}
<h3>We suggest the following:</h3>
<ol class="round">
    <li class="one">
        <h5>Getting Started</h5>
        ASP.NET MVC gives you a powerful, patterns-based way to build dynamic websites that
        enables a clean separation of concerns and that gives you full control over markup
        for enjoyable, agile development. ASP.NET MVC includes many features that enable
        fast, TDD-friendly development for creating sophisticated applications that use
        the latest web standards.
        <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=245151">Learn more…</a>
    </li>

    <li class="two">
        <h5>Add NuGet packages and jump-start your coding</h5>
        NuGet makes it easy to install and update free libraries and tools.
        <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=245153">Learn more…</a>
    </li>

    <li class="three">
        <h5>Find Web Hosting</h5>
        You can easily find a web hosting company that offers the right mix of features
        and price for your applications.
        <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=245157">Learn more…</a>
    </li>
</ol>
```

When running this website on localhost environment using Visual Studio Development Server, section 'featured' is rendered but if I pulish this website on my IIS, this section is not rendered. I don't know why?

Section 'featured' is a hidden feature in MVC? Are there any hidden features in MVC? Please help me to know more about MVC. Thanks.

Comment: Please read my question carefully. This MVC template example deployed on IIS has a UI be different from UI when running on Visual Studio Development Server.

Answer (score 3):

An old question but I see it hasn't been properly answered yet.

"Featured" is just a string which identifies a section of the site, it's not a keyword. The MVC example that comes with Visual Studio was made that way, but that by no means is a secret or special section in MVC. It's simply used to optionally hide or show this part with the blue background:

[image: http://i1.asp.net/umbraco-beta-media/38980/image001.png]

In the example, `_Layout.chtml` has this code:

```
<div id="body">
    @RenderSection("featured", required: false)
    <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
        @RenderBody()
    </section>
</div>
```

Which will render the following:

```
<div id="body">
    <section class="featured">
        /* Whatever you have in your view inside the @section featured { } */
    </section>
    <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
        /* Whatever you have in your view outside any @section */
    </section>
</div>
```

Again, where it reads "featured", you could replace that with any other word of your choice. ;)

More information about sections and `Render` methods [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/383145/RenderBody-RenderPage-and-RenderSection-methods-in).

Answer (score 1):

sure in Shared/_Layout.cshtml:

```
 @RenderSection("featured ", required: false)
```

or

```
@RenderSection("featured ", required: true)
```

Comment: Please remember I don't change codes but there is a difference about UI on IIS and Visual Studio Development Server???